# Can I override blocks in the parent template from Django templatetags?

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm writing a templatetag package for Django to make including RGraph graphs in Django apps easy.

I'm having a bit of trouble with the template that includes the javascript, I have a block defined in my base html file that I would like the templatetag's template to provide.

This is my top level template

```
{% load django_rgraph %}
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test Charts</title>
    {% block js %}
    {% block js.custom %}{% endblock %}
    {% endblock %}
</head>

<body>

{% rgraph piechart %}

</body>
</html>
```

and this is the template for my new tag

```
{% extends "django_rgraph/rgraph_base.html" %}

{% block rgraph_chart %}
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    var {{ chart.name }} = new RGraph.Pie('{{ chart.name }}', [{% for value in chart.values %}{{ value }}{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}]);
    {% for option, value in chart.options.items %}
    {{ chart.name }}.Set('{{ option }}', {{ value }});
    {% endfor %}

    {% if chart.animate %}
    RGraph.Effects.Pie.RoundRobin({{ chart.name }});
    {% else %}
    {{ chart.name }}.Draw();    
    {% endif %}
}
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

and for completeness, rgraph_base.html looks like this

```
{% block js.custom %}
{% for js in chart.js %}
<script src="RGraph/js/{{ js }}"></script>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}

{% block rgraph_chart %}Insert Chart Here{% endblock %}
```

I would expect this to create an html page where the javascript gets included in the header, but instead it appears in the body, like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test Charts</title>
</head>

<body>

<!-- I was expecting these script tags to be below the title tag -->
<script src="RGraph/js/RGraph.common.core.js"></script>
<script src="RGraph/js/RGraph.common.tooltips.js"></script>
<script src="RGraph/js/RGraph.common.effects.js"></script>
<script src="RGraph/js/RGraph.pie.js"></script>

<script>
window.onload = function() {
    var pie1 = new RGraph.Pie('pie1', [10,24,15,82]);
    pie1.Set('chart.gutter.left', 30);
    pie1.Draw();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

With this setup, with a template in the new tag overriding the block defined in the top level template, should I be able to have the scripts appear in the top head tag?

Comment: the script appears in the body because rgraph tag is inserted in to the body. no?

Comment: @akonsu, that's what I'm asking, in the tag's template there is a block of the same name as something in the parent, I was expecting the same behavior as normal templates, ie the block in the child would override the block in the parent.

Comment: apparently django templates do not behave like this. besides, it is questionable whether the behaviour that you expect is correct. after all you just insert your tag in to the body. you do not derive from the top level template that has the blocks that you want to fill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Akonsu is right, you have a misunderstanding of django template tags, they can't override other blocks.